# (Interactive?) table editing inside R

Tags: r

I am using Rmarkdown, but I guess the question also applies to a "simple" R script.
When I am writing a scientific report, I will sometimes create a custom table like this

```
my_tbl <- table (var1 = c("blab","bleb","blib","blob","blub"),
                 var2 = c("sblab","sbleb","sblib","sblob","sblub"),
                 var3 = c("lab","leb","lib","lob","lub"))
```

However, specifying the table entries horizontally like that can get messy, especially with a growing number of variables and entries.

I am wondering if there is a way of going more like this

```
my_tbl <- table(var1 = c("blab", ,var2 = c("sblab",  ,var3 = c("lab",
                         "bleb",           "sbleb",            "leb",
                         "blib",           "sblib",            "lib",
                         "blob",           "sblob",            "lob",
                         "blub")           "sblub")            "lub"))
```

Or even like this

```
                      var1   var2   var3
my_tbl <- table(     "blab" "sblab" "lab"
                     "bleb" "sbleb" "leb"
                     "blib" "sblib" "lib"
                     "blob" "sblob" "lob"
                     "blub" "sblub" "lub")
```

From INSIDE the editor.

So it is really about the "raw" R script/Rmarkdown document, not about its output.

I guess I am looking for an RStudio feature I haven't found yet.

I am fine with it being a "simple" editor thing or interactive, either way.

I have started looking into things such as the DT package but as far as I understand it, it will only allow for interactive content in my OUTPUT document, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: One way would be to use [`tibble::tribble()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html). This let's you specify your table vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I've added this as an answer, although - by definition - it is hard to demonstrate this via code!

I’ve heard a lot of good things about the package `DataEditR` (which enables you to interactively enter, filter and edit data). When I used it briefly, it seemed really impressive. Note that it also includes an RStudio add-in!

Here's a link: https://dillonhammill.github.io/DataEditR/

Answer (score 1):

The base `read.xxx` functions provide a way to do this with e.g.:

```
my_tbl <- read.delim( header=TRUE, sep=" ", text=
"var1 var2 var3
blab sblab lab
bleb sbleb leb
blib sblib lib
blob sblob lob
blub sblub lub")
```

Note that indenting the lines introduces spaces within the string, so doesn't get the desired output. This could be solved with the slightly more complex version:

```
my_tbl <- read.delim( header=TRUE, sep=" ", text=paste0(c(
  "var1 var2 var3",
  "blab sblab lab",
  "bleb sbleb leb",
  "blib sblib lib",
  "blob sblob lob",
  "blub sblub lub"), collapse="\n"))
```